Issues with Exporting Rigged Animation from Blender to Cinema 4D
I made a character animation with the Rigify add-on in Blender. I'm trying to use it in Cinema 4D by exporting from Blender. I tried exporting to both .abc and .fbx file formats and baked the pose animation several times. However, when exporting to an .abc file, some model parts are missing, and only the hair modeling is left.
Actually, I don't need the bones. Can anyone help me?



I found that I was due to render icon that I didn't checked
